# C# - Change array values inside a function

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, unity-game-engine

I attached a C# script to the trigger of an NPC in my scene. Basically I just try to let my NPC "talk" with the player. If the player is inside the trigger of the NPC and is pressing the "E" key, then the NPC should say the first untold message, defined in my array `messages`

The message disappears after 3 seconds, then the user is able to activate the NPC again, and the next message in the array should be selected and returned.

---

To solve this I created a bool array `messageStatus`, which holds the status which message was already told.

So index 0 of `messages` corresponds to index 0 of `messageStatus`.

I wrote a function called `selectMessage`, where I pass the two arrays, then get the first index position of the status array where the value is `false` and then return the message with that index. Then I set the status on that index to `true`, because the message was told.

However, it seems like the initialisation (`status[i] = true;`) is not changing the original array, but only the parameter. Because my NPC always tells the last message.

I think I have to pass the array as pointer, but I am not sure how this works and my attempts failed by far.

How can I solve this?

```
    string selectMessage(string[] messages, bool[] status)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= status.Length-1; i++) {

            if (status[i] == false) {
                status[i] = true;    //<-- problem
                return messages[i];
            }
        }

        return "Is everything ok?";
    }
```

---

**Complete Script:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TalkMalon : MonoBehaviour {

    public float displayTime = 3;
    public bool showMessage = false;

    public string[] messages = {
        "Hello, my name is Heinrich.",
        "I have nothing more to say."
    };

    public bool[] messageStatus = {
        false,
        false
    };

    void Update()
    {
        if (showMessage) {
            displayTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (displayTime <= 0.0) {
                showMessage = false;
                displayTime = 3;
            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerStay()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
            showMessage = true;
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (showMessage) {  
            GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 200f+100f, 200f), selectMessage(messages, messageStatus));
        }
    }

    string selectMessage(string[] messages, bool[] status)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= status.Length-1; i++) {

            if (status[i] == false) {
                status[i] = true;
                return messages[i];
            }
        }

        return "Is everything ok?";
    }
}
```

Comment: Use C#'s `ref` parameter support.

Comment: Slightly unrelated to your question but why not create a little class that contains the message and bool that describes whether it's been told. You then have a collection of these rather than 2 collections?

Comment: Use Dave's suggestion above or use a `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: Whats the issue here anyways?

Comment: Thank you for the tipps, i really appreciate them :) The issue is that my NPC always tells the last message

Answer (score 3):

I don't really see the need for two arrays. In the logic you show, you use the message array in order they were added to the collection. So you can just use an index:

```
int index = 0;
string[] messages;
string GetNextMessage()
{
    return (++index < messages.Length) ? messages[index] : "Is everything ok?"; 
}
```

This is actually better in the way you don't have to iterate the collection to find the next message. In algorithm, your solution is O(n) which means the worst case is the size of the collection. My solution is O(1) which means the worst case is one action.

Answer (score 1):

---

//first possible fix

```
string selectMessage(string[] messages,ref bool[] status)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= status.Length-1; i++) {

        if (status[i] == false) {
            status[i] = true;
            return messages[i];
        }
    }

    return "Is everything ok?";
}
```

---

Another option and more preferable is to make the messageStatus array static.

A better option is to implement an [`ObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx),

but it's a bit of overhead for your purpose...

//second possible fix

```
public static bool[] messageStatus = {
    false,
    false
};
```

Comment: Why is ref needed here? He's affecting the content of the array not the array reference. Why do you recommend static? No need either.

Answer (score 0):

I turned out that the problem was somewhere else and it was not even necessary to pass the array as reference by using `ref` or pointers. But I am glad that you guys recommended it and appreciate your very helpful tips!

It was a logical mistake. I think the last message was always shown because OnGUI is executed every frame (afaik)?

I changed the logic according to @Everts suggestion, which is much better obviously. I removed the status array which was not needed at all.

**Fixed Script:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TalkMalon : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int index = 0;
    private string currentMessage = "";
    private float displayTime = 3;
    private bool showMessage = false;
    private bool selectNextMessage = false;

    public string[] messages = {
        "Hello, my name is Heinrich.",
        "I have nothing more to say."
    };

    void Update()
    {
        if (showMessage) {
            displayTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (displayTime <= 0.0) {
                showMessage = false;
                displayTime = 3;

                Debug.Log(messages.Length);

                if (index != messages.Length - 1) {
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerStay()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
            showMessage = true;
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (showMessage) {
            GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 200f, 200f), messages[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are about to get some out of bound exception. In OnTriggerStay, showMessage = (index < messages.Length);

Comment: Im not sure what exactly you are referring to? In OnTriggerStay there is no code like `showMessage = (index < messages.Length);`. I tested the code and there were no expections.

Comment: If u keep going to the NPC, press E, as index is never set back to 0, it will keep increasing. You need to prevent the index to get higher than messages. Length. The line I gave will prevent yo run the code if index is too big.

Comment: @Everts, I already prevent it with the line `if (index != messages.Length - 1) {`